# É possível visualizar todo o conteúdo de um namespace em C++?

Tags: c, c++, namespace, using

Quando você faz a diretiva:

```
using namespace std; //primeira forma
```

Você obtém acesso direto a **todos** elementos do namespace std.
Mas imagine que você quer utilizar somente o `std::cout` ou `std::endl`
logo seria melhor utilizar a diretiva:

```
using std::cout;  //segunda forma
using std::endl;
```

Assim você só obteria os objetos que **precisa usar** não todos. 
A minha pergunta é: existe uma forma de visualizar tudo o que é adicionado quando se utiliza o comando `using namespace std;`?

Algo como (eu sei que isso está altamente errado):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << std;

return 0;
}
```

O meu questionamento é no seguinte sentido: 
Eu li que é preferível utilizar a segunda forma de diretiva using mencionada do que utilizar a forma geral. O livro explicava que geralmente a primeira forma adiciona coisas que vc não usa. Então eu queria saber se existe uma forma de visualizar essas ''coisas''. De qualquer jeito eu já achei a resposta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123958/is-it-possible-to-view-all-the-contents-of-a-namespace-in-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No sentido de visibilidade de escopo ao longo do programa,**

sim, é possível visualizar todo o conteúdo de um namespace porque não dá para definir no escopo do namespace coisas privadas (ou seja, se não criar no namescape um escopo de classe ou estrutura ou qualquer coisa que possibilite privatizar o dado, esse dado será público). E não é necessário utilizar o "using", pois só serve para facilitar a digitação.

Exemplo.

```
namespace Math {
    class Point {
        float x ;
    public:
        float y ;
    } ;
    static Point origen ;
}
```

Neste caso, você pode acessar o tipo Math::Point, o dado Math::origen e até o campo Math::origen.y, mas não pode acessar Math::origen.x. Se voce usar `using namespace Math ;`, dará no mesmo escrever Point e Math::Point, também dará no mesmo origen e Math::origen, etc. Só não dará no mesmo se houver algo ambíguo, como alguma coisa que tenha o mesmo nome fora do escopo, aí o uso do nome estendido com o escopo o especifica, assim tirando a ambiguidade.

**No sentido de visualização humana dos recursos do namespace,**

sim, tem editores, como o do Visual Studio para Visual C++, que possibilita saber tudo que está definido num namespace. Basta, por exemplo, digitar "std::" e logo que botar o último caracter aparece a lista de classes, variáveis, funções, etc que se encontram em "std". Você pode selecionar na lista (ao invés de digitar) o que você quer usar, assim facilita a chamada das funções em caso de desconhecimento do nome da função que quer usar. Outra forma de saber o que há nos namespaces é pesquisar na internet sobre as bibliotecas.

Não conheço outras formas de fazer isso. Inclusive, o namespace pelo que sei somente existe em tempo de compilação, portanto é difícil gerar uma saída que envolva o namespace em si ao invés de seu conteúdo.

Comment: Creio que você não tenha entendido a pergunta. O desejado é colocar `using namespace Math` e, programaticamente, descobrir que tem `origen` e `Point` dentro do namespace

Comment: A pergunta dele não é clara, tem múltiplas interpretações. Também faz parecer que ele não sabe bem o que é o namespace. Quando fala em "using std::cout; using std::endl;", ele fala como se using fosse para dar visibilidade.

Comment: Coloquei um pouco mais na minha resposta levando em conta o que você falou.

Comment: Muita boa a parte da edição. Vou ler com mais calma assim que possível.

Comment: O meu questionamento foi no seguinte sentido: Eu li que é preferível utilizar a segunda forma de diretiva using mencionada na pergunta do que utilizar a forma geral. O livro explicava que geralmente a primeira forma adiciona coisas que vc não usa. Então eu queria saber se existe uma forma de visualizar essas ''coisas''. De qualquer jeito eu já achei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

> Você obtém acesso direto a todos elementos do namespace std

Isso não é verdade.

Quando você faz a diretiva:

```
using namespace std;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/AccessNamespace.cpp).

você não obtém acesso direto a todos elementos do *namespace* `std`, apenas diz que você não precisa colocar o `namespace` determinado na frente de cada membro dele, só não há mais a necessidade de qualificar todo identificador. Ele não é um importador de nada, tanto que precisa colocar o `#include` para tudo que pretende usar.

Esse mecanismo é apenas um agrupador de nomes, nada mais que isso. Não deve, mas você pode até mesmo criar algo e dizer que está no `std`. Qualquer um pode fazer isto. Então como listar tudo o que existe? Não faz sentido.

Qualquer coisa que deseje usar você deve saber bem sobre ela, então não precisa saber sobre tudo o que tem em um espaço de nomes, isso é irrelevante.

Se quer saber o que tem disponível consulte a documentação. Não tem nada oficial, mas uma fonte próxima disso é o [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123958/is-it-possible-to-view-all-the-contents-of-a-namespace-in-c/45123996#45123996 isso sim responde.

Comment: Não entendi, diz basicamente a mesma coisa.